Increasing number of threads increase execution time. (C)
I'm trying to write a C program with a Mac M1, intended to load data from a big file (several gigabytes).
I've implemented the following :
Each thread receive a pointer to a structure were are stored the address of a file's region distinct mapping (using mmap with flags MAP_PRIVATE and PROT_READ), and a dynamic (distinct at each thread) subarray to fill.
I tried previously a variation of this code, with a unique mapping of the whole file, and a unique array as global variable, the performances are the same. (To be honest, I tried everything I could.)
With 2 or 3 threads, I get almost the same performance, in terms of execution time, than with 1 thread ; and with 5, 8, 16, and 32 threads, it gets worse than with 1, 2 or 3 threads.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing huge mistakes, but cannot figure out what.
My questions is : What could cause this behaviour ?

You can't speed up IO bound operations by throwing more threads at it.

"I'm pretty sure I'm doing huge mistakes" Assuming that more threads will always result in more performance is such a mistake. If the underlying task cannot be executed well in parallel, more threads will only create more overhead. Limiting scenarios are: A) One thread depends on result from another thread. B) Or all threads require access to the same resource wich is the bottleneck. In both cases more threads only cause more waiting.

@tkausl Thank you very much for your answer.
Isn't a purpose of mmap to avoid system calls and access the file as if it was in memory ? Is it problem of file size ?

@Gerhardh Thank you for your answer.
No thread waits for another thread's result.
As each thread uses it's own mapped region of the file (no overlapping), no thread reads from exactly the same place in the file that another thread will read from, each thread writes in its own array, what is bottlenecking ?

Isn't a purpose of mmap to avoid system calls and access the file as if it was in memory ? Accessing the file as if it was in memory is just a "magic trick". It isn't in memory. As soon as you access the first byte of the file, a page fault will be issued which the kernel uses to load a chunk of the file to memory. If you access a byte of the file outside of the loaded region it will page fault again to load more data. Its transparent to the user process but certainly not free.

The file itself or the SSD where it is stored it the relevant resource you are accessing from all threads and that is the bottleneck. Not a specific location in the file, You can't get the same amount of data over the same hardware interface in less time just by sending more requests.

your results sound on par with expectations.  one thing at a time has, can have, some dead time at the target.  having a few workers can suck up some of that dead time.  But to many workers now the path between you and the target is the bottleneck.  Think of folks draining a tub using buckets and having to stay on one sidewalk.  A few folks will do it faster, but 100 folks and (not doing a bucket brigade) the sidewalk becomes the bottleneck  as well as the I/O on the target.  push it even harder and the processor and bus and target are all overloaded.

Having a curve that performance increases with increases in parallelism but then peaks and falls off is expected.  Where and why varies (not just for accessing a device, even just operations in memory).  And each system varies so not all will reach the peak.

Your SSD can handle only so many operations per second, and - critically - only one at a time. Everything other than the current request will just have to queue and wait. The controller is, in effect, enforcing single-threading.
You're I/O bound. Multithreading gains you no benefit.
